# CSS lobotomized owl -VS- :not(:first-child)?

Tags: css, layout, css-selectors, spacing

The owl `* + *` looks nice(though not as readable in my opinion), but is that the only reason it's popular?
Is there otherwise no difference between this:

```
div > * + * {margin-top: 20px;}
```

And this?:

```
div > *:not(:first-child) {margin-top: 20px;}
```

Comment: In this case there is no much difference, much like `2 + 2` and `2 * 2` are both equal to `4`, but the addition and multiplication have their own purposes in different scenarios.

Comment: In addition to what was already mentioned, both rules also have different specificity - first one has 0-0-1, second one has 0-1-1. _Must_ not make a difference, but _might_ in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Browser support for the owl](https://caniuse.com/?search=css%202.1%20selectors) is "everything newer than IE 6".

[Browser support for `:not`](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Anot) is weaker, in particular it isn't supported by any version of Internet Explorer.

---

Not that many developers consider IE worth supporting today, but there are some, and habits from years of needing to use techniques that support it die hard.